# How to submit and display form data onto another page in rails without using controllers?

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a form which takes various inputs and when clicking on submit it should display those params data on to another page. For example, I have a form called enter_invoice.html.erb

I have written the following html code for it.

```
<%= form_tag('/generate_invoice', remote: true, multipart: true, type: :post )    
do |f| %>
 <input type="text" name="order[txnid]" placeholder="Enter your txnid" /><br>
 <input type="number" name="order[stamp_amount]" placeholder="Stamp amount" />
 <br>
 <input type="text" name="order[payment][created_at][strftime]" 
 placeholder="Payment Created at" /><br>
 <input type="text" name="order[payment][mode]" placeholder="Payment mode" />
 <br>
 <input type="text" name="order[user][profile][first_name]" placeholder="User 
 First name" /><br>

<input type="submit" class="submit action-button" /><br>

 <% end %>
```

Now I have another form called genrate_invoice.html.erb.The data I enter in enter_invoice should display on generate_invoice.

```
<html lang="">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"> 
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 </head>
<body style="margin:0 auto;padding:0;max-width:595px;font-family: 
 'PFBeauSansPro' 'Tahoma';font-weight:thin;font-size: 14px;background-size: 
  cover;ont-family: 'PFBeauSansPro';font-weight: thin !important;"> 
 TNXid : <%= @order.txnid %><br>
 Stamp_amount : <%= @order.stamp_amount %> <br/>
 Created_at : <%= @order.payment.created_at.strftime %> <br/>
 Address: <%= @order.address.address1 %><br/>
        :
        :

 </body>
 </html>
```

So how do I submit this data to be displayed on the generate_invoice.html.erb.

Newbie still in rails. Please guide me.

Comment: Yes, you'll need a controller for this.

Comment: You, being a rails newbie, will benefit greatly from the [rails tutorial](https://www.railstutorial.org)

Comment: i don't know what you are trying to achieve, because 1/2 part of rails is about controllers. however ou can use cache. put two pages on public folder (foo.html, bar.html) store submitted information in a cache, then retrieve all them from cache. that's another thing - for all those you don't need rails.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are trying to do is input data into a single object in a number of steps. Avoiding controllers is not the best solution.

If you are new to rails, I'd suggest you have a look at the [wicked gem](https://github.com/schneems/wicked). That will help you build a multi-step input.

Alternatively, you can build you own solution by:

- adding a state machine to the object being updated (to track at what point in the process the object is),
- using a form partial to match each object state, and modifying the view so that it picks the partial that matches the current object state.
- and then use form objects to do things like validation this is consistent with the current state. Have a look at the [reform gem](https://github.com/trailblazer/reform) if you are unfamiliar with form objects.